# UINavigationController stops animating when pushing controllers?

Tags: iphone, ios

I use 1 UINavigationController in my app, and everytime I push a UIViewController I always set the animated option to YES. However, at some point in my app, it just stops animating. Normally when I push an UIViewController, the screen turns from right to left. Now, it just suddenly appears without any animation.

What could cause this to happen? I am always pushing with animated:YES, so is there something that is interfering with a global animation setting?

In case it helps, I'm also using MBProgressHUD at several points in my app.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I faced with the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm it seems the problem was caused because I was calling reloadData on a table inside a thread that wasn't the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

A couple possibilities include low memory or the thread blocking somewhere. Are you doing much processing on the main thread during this animation?